# SO used to delete comments asking for upvotes or marking as answers--did it stop?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

IIRC these comments used to be automagically cleaned up, or required only a single flag (I could be recalling incorrectly). What's the current process for those?

Ignore? Flag as chatty? Other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this still happens. Flag them as "no longer needed".

If the text of the comment matches an undisclosed regex, it will be automatically deleted in response to your flag. Otherwise, it will be reviewed by a moderator and subsequently deleted.

These are the *perfect* types of comments to flag as "no longer needed" (along with "I updated the answer; please check"). Please continue doing so! We appreciate your efforts towards keeping the site clean.

Comment: 'undisclosed', hmm?

Comment: The exact regex used to determine which comments will be insta-deleted upon a single flag is intentionally not made public, @JL2210. But it includes things like “thanks”, “+1”, and a variety of curse words. (Or did you mean the grammar mistake? Fixed now.)

Comment: It seems to be very selective in its choices. For example, if I flag a simple comment that contains "Thanks for your help!" it will be instantly deleted, but if I flag a comment that says "Thanks for your help! One more question, ..." it won't.

Comment: Length also matters, @JL2210. For exactly the case you cite: only the first sentence of that comment would obviously qualify as “no longer needed”. The rest may be asking a genuine clarification question, which is an appropriate use of comments. That comment may still qualify for removal if the answer to the follow-up question has been edited into the answer proper, but that requires a human moderator to make the call.

Comment: It would actually be useful if you published a selection of the words that trigger the regex. I've seen a few requests for a way to make self-deleting comments – it would be nice to know that I can make a comment that will go away when done without bothering a mod.

Comment: Just front-load all your comments with expletives, @divibisan. Then they'll be sure to trip the regex. Wait, on second thought, that might end up bothering a mod... (On a more practical note, don't be overly concerned about "bothering" the mods. Cleaning stuff up is kinda what we're here for.)

Comment: @divibisan Yes, it would be useful for people wanting to know exactly how to skirt the detection of bad content; for that exact reason, they *don't* publish it, as Cody said.

Comment: @TylerH I understand that. But they could mention 1 word from the regex without compromising it. Then, we could write self deleting bothering mods with "No longer needed flags". But it doesn't sound like that's a problem in the first place

Comment: @CodyGray Well, ok then, I won't feel bad about it. Let me just say thanks for all the hard work you (and all the other mods, both active and on strike) do for this site!

Answer (score 4):

I would just flag as No Longer Needed and move on. Unless there's something egregious going on (i.e. repeated vote begging) there's not a clear CoC(red) flag condition here

As for automatic cleanup, this still happens. I tried to post a simple answer on another Meta and it was automatically made a comment. You can also flag "Thanks!" or similar comments as NLN and those typically are automatically removed.